# How can I implement globalization on hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

I have three hyperlink English, Spanish, and Chinese. When a user clicks on Spanish, all the content of website will change into Spanish (and so on). I tried to find an answer for this on Google but didn't get a perfect answer. If you have any links, could you please share with me. I don't know how to implement globalization.

Note:-I am try to implement on Hyperlink.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to consider using a parameterized string as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1262856/227646 ? Have you had a chance to look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx ?

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that uses a ComboBox to switch between languages. The tutorial saves the last culture selected in the Session collection.  You could store it in a cookie if you would like it to be persistent across visits.

[Localization Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15313/Globalization-and-localization-demystified-in-ASP)